# When to use AALTO and when WoodStox for xml processing with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, woodstox, jackson-modules

Reading [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773649/java-xml-parser-performance-sun-java-streaming-xml-parser-sjsxp-vs-woodsto)

> Aalto is by far fastest of the three, especially for parsing. It is commonly 50% - 100% faster than either Woodstox or SJSXP. One downside is that it does not handle DTDs (and thereby not external entities; it handles pre-defined and character entities).

it seems that Aalto is the recommended way to read/write xml with jackson. However on [jackson-dataformat-xml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#maven-dependency) page it recommends using Woodstox, which has not been updated for some time.

So what is the best way forward? Woodstox or Aalto?

Comment: One small note on Woodstox releases: part of reason for few releases is that it is very mature, complete and bug-free. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it". But there has been a new release (4.3.0) to add one feature that was missing, ability to limit expansion of parsed entities (needed to protect against certain forms of denial-of-service attacks using XML parsed entities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that Woodstox is the safest choice for correct operation, given its wide functionality and being de facto Stax standard implementation -- most Java XML/Soap frameworks use Woodstox. So if you just want least hassle all around, it is a good choice.

But Aalto is significantly faster, and its features set is perfectly fine for Jackson XML module: DTD processing is not needed for JAXB-style data-binding.

So I would say that this comes back to how much you value performance (Aalto) and how much simple no-hassle "it just works with no problems whatsoever" (Woodstox).
That is how I would choose myself, if I was developing system myself.

Besides, switching from one to the other is trivially easy: so one possibility is to try Aalto; and only if you face an issue (FWIW, there are no reported issue with Aalto/Jackson, as per issue tracker -- these are hypothetical issues).